# Can you help me solve this triple integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I've been trying to solve this integral $$\int^{-1}_{-2} \int^{-1}_{-2} \int^{-1}_{-2} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$$ If I try some variable change like $$x=\sqrt{y^2+z^2} tan \theta $$ things complicated a lot. Wolfram alpha whit numerical method says that the integral is 0.33333 which makes me think that is possible to obtain an analytical solution. This problem is part of a example test for a master admission.

Im also thinking about change to spherical coordinates wich lead me to
$$\int\int\int r^2 sin \theta cos \phi sin \phi drd\theta d\phi$$ but now I dont have clear my integration limits.

Comment: $ \displaystyle \int^{-1}_{-2} \int^{-1}_{-2} \int^{-1}_{-2} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} ~ dx ~ dy ~ dz$ $ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{3} \int^{-1}_{-2} \int^{-1}_{-2} \int^{-1}_{-2} \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} ~ dx ~ dy ~ dz$

Comment: @MathLover thank you, I see it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use symmetry. The integral will be the same with $y^2$ or $z^2$ in the numerator. But adding all three gives the integral of $1$ over the cube.

Comment: Oh men, I didnt see that. Thank you, I was overthinking the problem I guess.

Comment: Symmetry is something you should keep.an eye out for in all sorts of mathematics!